# reference datatable column in html string C#

Tags: c#, html

Building an string named html in the aspx.CS page using C# language.

Assuming DataTable dt.

This obviously doesn't work:

```
string html = "dt["FirstName"]";
```

Neither does this:

```
string html = "dt[\"FirstName\"]";
```

Neither does this:

```
string html = ""+dt+"[\"FirstName\"]";
```

Full Code (was really just trying to keep this question simple, but this might help for understanding):

```
public static string ConvertDataTableToHtmlTable(DataTable dt)
{
    string html = "<h3>Locations:</h3><table class=\"table table-condensed\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\">";
    //add header row
    html += "<thead><tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>City</th><th>Contact</th><th>Stations</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

        int i = 1;
        //add rows
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
        //visible row
        html += "<tr data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-target=\"#demo"+i+"\" class=\"accordion-toggle\">";
        html += "<td><button class=\"btn btn-default btn-xs\" onclick=\"return false;\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal\"></span></button></td>";
        html += "<td>"+dt[\"CompanyCity\"]+</td>";
        html += "<td>"+dt[\"FirstName\"]+</td>";
        html += "<td> 11 </td></tr>"; 
        //collapsable row
            html += "<tr><td colspan = \"12\" class=\"hiddenRow\"><div class=\"accordian-body collapse\" id=\"demo"+i+"\">";
            html += "<table class=\"table table-striped\"><thead>";
            html += "<tr><th>License Key</th><th>Start</th><th>Expire</th><th>Product</th><th>Version</th><th>Level</th><th>Model</th><th>User</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
            html += "<tr><td>Instalcode </td><td> start </td><td> expire </td><td> product </td><td> version </td><td> level </td><td> model </td><td> user </td><td> email </td></tr>";
            html += "</tbody></table></div></td></tr>";
        i++;
        }
    html += "</tbody></table>";
    return html;
}
```

Page load (dtActive is the datatable with data)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 locationsTable.InnerHtml = ConvertDataTableToHtmlTable(dtActive);
}
```

ASPX Page:

```
<div id="locationsTable" runat="server"></div>
```

Any help is appreciated and of course if you need me to be more specific, or if this is a duplicate please comment below with your request/link. Thank you

Comment: This is C# string, not HTML.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JameCoderBot How are you printing the string to the page and what is the result of those three strings that you tried?

Comment: ok i will post full code so you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the records of the datatable

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt)
{
    String firstname = dr["FirstName"] != null ? dr["FirstName"].ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```

**edit**

Based on your editing:

You're iterating but using the wrong reference, use `row["FirstName"]` instead of `dt["FirstName"]`

Comment: Are you sure that's what the OP actually wants?

Comment: Well he seems to be trying to get a field named "FirstName" directly from a DataTable instead of a row of it.

Comment: THis might work. so i put it like this dt["+firstname+"]   ?

Comment: Nevermind, question has been edited and now makes more sense.

Comment: @JamesCoderBot no! Instead try to get the value from 'row'. See my edited answer

Comment: Excellent. Thank you r1verside. The reason there are no other questions like this is because it shouldn't exist in the first place.